# What is "Narnia-like"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw an article on CNN use the phrase "Narnia-like" to describe the town of Dixville Notch in [The effort to save New Hampshire's midnight vote](http://www.cnn.com/2016/02/03/politics/new-hampshire-primary-midnight-vote-dixville-notch/index.html).

The most characteristic aspect of Narnia is talking animals. I don't think Dixville Notch is full of talking animals.

What did the author mean by that? Is this a term used by others to mean the same thing?

Comment: It's a sylvan area with a continental climate far from major centers of population or commerce, one that seems very distant even though it might as well be accessible on the other side of a wardrobe, a place idealized in literature and home to inhabitants who are likewise mythologized. Talking animals seem very incidental.

Comment: @choster That seems a strange view. Did you read the Narnia books? There are lots of remote places. They could have said Montana-like if that's all they meant. The animals are the unique aspect of Narnia.

Comment: This is CNN. They're not catering to Lewis aficionados, but to the general public, and to the general public, Narnia is largely indistiguishable from Middle-Earth, Westeros, or any other high fantasy setting.

Comment: @choster In which case that adjective would be meaningless? What are you getting at?

Comment: Maybe it’s always winter there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware (I'm a native English speaker who has lived in two parts of the United States, Missouri and Oklahoma), Narnia-like has no specific meaning in the English language. Thus, I'm inclined to believe that they probably saw one of the Chronicles of Narnia movies (from the video on the article, likely the [first one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Witch_and_the_Wardrobe)) and associated the landscape with Narnia. This fits well with the icy descriptor they use right before it, as Narnia in "The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe" was covered by snow due to the White Witch.

Comment: You think they're just assuming all of Narnia is snowy all the time? That would seem to match the journalistic standards at CNN.

Comment: XD. I've found most television and internet news sources to be like that.

Answer (score 1):

The journalist was attempting to sound literary and/or poetic.  He or she was also talking through his or her hat. The expression is a nonce thing, a one-off, and rather ditzy at that.

As a lifelong inhabitant of the region, I can bear reliable witness to the fact that while the damn deer get smarter every hunting season, neither they nor any of the other indiginous fauna are capable of speech. (C.S. Lewis thought that part up out of sheer imagination, perhaps encouraged by the pints and drams shared with Tolkien.)

Dixville Notch, resident population 12, is in Coos County, New Hampshire.  To get there, drive to the middle of Nowhere, and then continue another 37 miles.  If the beaver start to accost you in French, you have gone too far, and you will have to re-cross the Canadian border.

If you ask someone in, say, Littleton or Wolfboro for directions, they will likely reply, "You can't get there from here."

Dixville Notch *is* very beautiful. It is the site of a grand old resort hotel, The Balsams. Look closely at the picture, but you will probably not see any lions.

[image]

*Well, you asked...*